# How create a QueryExpression with null field in PocoDynamo

Tags: c#, servicestack, amazon-dynamodb, pocodynamo

I want query over GSI when a range key is null. I have this code, but it thrown a exception

```
IPocoDynamo dbDynamo = new PocoDynamo(new AmazonDynamoDBClient());
var queryExpression = dbDynamo.FromQueryIndex<IndexName>(x => x.InvalidFrom == (DateTime?)null);
var response = dbDynamo.Query(queryExpression);
```

My model looks like this

```
[References(typeof(IndexName))]
[Alias("TableName")]
public class Child
{
   [AutoIncrement]
   public int ChildId { get; set; }

   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   public string Key { get; set; }
   public DateTime? InvalidFrom { get; set; }
   public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is my index

```
public class IndexName: IGlobalIndex<Child>
{
   [HashKey]
   public int ParentId { get; set; }

   [RangeKey]
   public DateTime? InvalidFrom { get; set; }

   public int ChildId { get; set; }
}
```

What i am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly when you use a query you always need to supply the Hash in the Query, so it needs a minimum of:

```
var q = dbDynamo.FromQueryIndex<IndexName>(x => 
    x.ParentId = parentId && x.InvalidFrom == (DateTime?)null);
```

But trying to insert an item without a `InvalidFrom` value, e.g:

```
db.PutItem(new Child { ParentId = 2, Key = "Key2", Value = 2 });
```

Will succeed when `Child` doesn't have an Global Index, but will fail when it has a `IndexName` containing a nullable `DateTime?` Range Key with:

```
Invalid attribute value type
```

Essentially AWS wont let you insert a `NULL` value when it's defined on a Global Index Range Key, but it will let you insert a NULL value on a non-RangeKey property. So this use-case isn't supported.

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth PocoDynamo now supports .net core